# How to obfuscate a java based project

Tags: java, netbeans, obfuscation

I have created a java based project using Netbeans as an IDE. Now I want to obfuscate my project. How can this be done?

Comment: Obfuscation is better at reducing the download size than protecting code.

Comment: ProGuard is now shipped with Netbeans:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/15141108/1686442

Comment: @NickVeys u r genius.. huh.. :/

Answer (score 4):

You need to use a source obfuscator.

I have  used [Zelix Klassmaster](http://www.zelix.com/klassmaster/index.html?id=010) in the past and it is pretty good.

Comment: how do we use it with Java SE application?

Answer (score 3):

I have used [RetroGuard](http://www.retrologic.com/retroguard-main.html) and i was really happy with it. The thing I really liked was the ability to use it from my build file, so that I could deploy the project directly obfuscated.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at proguard - you can integrate it into ANT.