# Java Code Obfuscate

Tags: java, obfuscation

What is a good free java code Obfuscate program? I have heard of ProGuard but all I get is class not found when I run my applet so uhm... yeah -- anyone?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to obfuscate a java based project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643517/how-to-obfuscate-a-java-based-project)

Comment: maybe it helps more if you reframe the question as "How to use Proguard to obfuscate an applet without encountering ClassNotFoundExceptions" wherein you put the detailed steps/configurations you used to obfuscate it and add detailed information about the exception itself (message, trace, etc).

Comment: I tried with minimal options and I think it's because of the class names.

Comment: Read the first answer of the duplicate question.  It is about how to use ProGuard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ProGuard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/) is a good one.

> ProGuard is a free Java class file
>   shrinker, optimizer, obfuscator, and
>   preverifier. It detects and removes
>   unused classes, fields, methods, and
>   attributes. It optimizes bytecode and
>   removes unused instructions. It
>   renames the remaining classes, fields,
>   and methods using short meaningless
>   names. Finally, it preverifies the
>   processed code for Java 6 or for Java Micro Edition.

Answer (score 1):

yGuard is one I have used. It is open source, so you can try it out.
http://www.yworks.com/en/products_yguard_about.html

I would be interested to know why your application is failing however. I have heard ProGuard is good, so maybe you are using wrong settings when you obfuscate?

Answer (score 0):

Try arxan.com .  I have not used it but I watched their presentation a year ago in cjug.

http://proguard.sourceforge.net/ also looks good.

Answer (score 0):

You can look to good list Java Obfuscator [here](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/obfuscator.html). If you want to have free obfuscator than you can use [JBCO](http://www.sable.mcgill.ca/JBCO/), [Marvin Obfuscator](http://freshmeat.net/projects/marvinobfuscator), [Proguard](http://sourceforge.net/projects/proguard/), [YGuard](http://www.yworks.com/products/yguard/).